# Cannot locate resource 'application_startup'

Tags: wpf

I have just started `WPF` now. I am assigning `startupURI` page from code behind. It gives me this error:

> Cannot locate resource 'application_startup'"

here is what I done in App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="HelloWpf.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

Here is what I have done in App.xaml.cs file:

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the startup window
        MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
        // Do stuff here, e.g. to the window
        wnd.Title = "Something else";
        // Show the window
        wnd.Show();

        //Application.Current.MainWindow = wnd;
        //wnd.InitializeComponent();
        //wnd.Show();
    }
```

Please help what's wrong in this simple code.Thanks

Comment: event name is `Startup`, not `StartupUri` (that one is property). subscribe the handler properly: `Startup="Application_Startup"`

Comment: that worked.thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StartupUri` is used to specify the file name of the window object to be loaded when the application starts. `Startup` is the event to subscribe to if you want to do something during application start up.

Answer (score 5):

Change your xaml to below code. It should work.

```
<Application x:Class="HelloWpf.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```